# Cannot resolve constructor 'BaseBar(java.time.ZonedDateTime, java.lang.Double)'?

Tags: java, android

So I'm an amateur Android developer and have an issue.
My app uses this library (https://github.com/ta4j/ta4j) but after updating it to the latest stable release I'm having these errors!

Here's the error:

```
Cannot resolve constructor 'BaseBar(java.time.ZonedDateTime, java.lang.Double, java.lang.Double, java.lang.Double, java.lang.Double, java.lang.Double)'
```

Here's the java code of my class:

```
public class RVCardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVCardAdapter.CryptoViewHolder> {

    //globals
    private List<SingleCryptoData> mCryptos;
    private int mExpandedPosition;
    //private int previousExpandedPosition = -1;


    //default constructor
    public RVCardAdapter() {
        super();
        mCryptos = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    //this refreshes the list
    public void clear() {
        mCryptos.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    //this adds the POJO passed into the crypto list
    public void addData(SingleCryptoData crypto) {
        mCryptos.add(crypto);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CryptoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cryptocurrency_card, viewGroup, false);
        return new CryptoViewHolder(v);
    }

    //onBindViewHolder binds the data to the layout elements for each crypto
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CryptoViewHolder cryptoViewHolder, int i) {

        //loading animation
        FiftyShadesOf fiftyShades = new FiftyShadesOf(cryptoViewHolder.mCardViewDetails.getContext());
        fiftyShades.on(cryptoViewHolder.mSignal, cryptoViewHolder.mCardViewDetails, cryptoViewHolder.mSignalStrength);
        fiftyShades.fadein(true);
        fiftyShades.start();

        //set up output formatting
        Currency usd = Currency.getInstance("USD");
        NumberFormat currencyFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
        currencyFormat.setCurrency(usd);

        NumberFormat twoDecimalFormat = DecimalFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
        twoDecimalFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.FLOOR);
        twoDecimalFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
        twoDecimalFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);

        //TODO get display POJO data
        cryptoViewHolder.mCryptoName.setText(mCryptos.get(i).getName());
        cryptoViewHolder.mCryptoValue.setText(currencyFormat.format(mCryptos.get(i).getRaw().getPrice()));
        cryptoViewHolder.mCryptoSymbol.setText(mCryptos.get(i).getRaw().getFromSymbol());
        cryptoViewHolder.mCryptoDetailsVolume.setText(twoDecimalFormat.format(mCryptos.get(i).getRaw().getVolume24Hour()) + " " + mCryptos.get(i).getRaw().getFromSymbol());
        cryptoViewHolder.mCryptoDetailsLow.setText(currencyFormat.format(mCryptos.get(i).getRaw().getLow24Hour()));
        cryptoViewHolder.mCryptoDetailsHigh.setText(currencyFormat.format(mCryptos.get(i).getRaw().getHigh24Hour()));
        cryptoViewHolder.mCryptoDetailsOpen.setText(currencyFormat.format(mCryptos.get(i).getRaw().getOpen24Hour()));
        cryptoViewHolder.mCryptoDetailsPercentChange.setText(twoDecimalFormat.format(mCryptos.get(i).getRaw().getChangePercent24Hour()) + " %");

        //color percent change depending on value
        if (mCryptos.get(i).getRaw().getChangePercent24Hour() >= 0) {
            cryptoViewHolder.mCryptoDetailsPercentChange.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#52BE80"));
        } else {
            cryptoViewHolder.mCryptoDetailsPercentChange.setTextColor(Color.RED);

        }


        //handles expanding animation

        //TODO stop first card from expanding
        final boolean isExpanded = cryptoViewHolder.getAdapterPosition() == mExpandedPosition;
        cryptoViewHolder.mCardViewDetails.setVisibility((isExpanded) ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        cryptoViewHolder.itemView.setActivated(isExpanded);

//        if (isExpanded)
//            previousExpandedPosition = cryptoViewHolder.getAdapterPosition();

        cryptoViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            mExpandedPosition = (isExpanded) ? -1 : cryptoViewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
            //notifyItemChanged(previousExpandedPosition);  //this used to close the
            notifyItemChanged(cryptoViewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        });


        //HISTODATA API
        CryptoCompareAPI service = ServiceFactory.createRetrofitRx(CryptoCompareAPI.class, CryptoCompareAPI.BASE_URL);


        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26){
            //DAYS OF HISTORY TO GET FOR EACH CRYPTO
            int historyDays = 14;

            service.getHistoricalData(mCryptos.get(i).getRaw().getFromSymbol(), "USD", historyDays, "CryptoAnalysis")
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new Observer<HistoData>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                        }

                        //in histodata, the last element is the newest, and is yesterday. it will be at position [days]
                        @Override
                        public void onNext(HistoData histoData) {

                            TimeSeries series = new BaseTimeSeries("Strategy");

                            //TODO make usable on API 21+
                            ZonedDateTime endTime = ZonedDateTime.now().minusDays(historyDays);

                            //loop for each day of results in histodata
                            for (int i = 0; i < histoData.getData().size(); i++) {

                                //create a new base bar
                                Bar bar = new BaseBar(
                                        endTime.plusDays(i),
                                        histoData.getData().get(i).getOpen(),
                                        histoData.getData().get(i).getHigh(),
                                        histoData.getData().get(i).getLow(),
                                        histoData.getData().get(i).getClose(),
                                        histoData.getData().get(i).getVolumeTo()
                                );

                                series.addBar(bar);

                            }


                            //RUN ANALYSIS
                            Signal signal = TechnicalAnalysis.getSignal(series);

                            //INFLATE LAYOUT STUFF
                            cryptoViewHolder.mSignal.setText(signal.getSignalResult());
                            cryptoViewHolder.mRsiValue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            cryptoViewHolder.mRsiValue.setText(String.valueOf((int) signal.getRsiStrength()));
                            cryptoViewHolder.mMomentumValue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            cryptoViewHolder.mMomentumValue.setText(String.valueOf((int) signal.getMomentumStrength()));
                            cryptoViewHolder.mEmaValue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            cryptoViewHolder.mEmaValue.setText(String.valueOf((int) signal.getEmaStrength()));
                            //cryptoViewHolder.mSignalStrength.setText("(" + String.valueOf(signal.getSignalStrength()) + ")");


                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {

                            if (e.getMessage() != null)
                                Log.e("Histo API Error", e.getMessage());

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete() {

                            fiftyShades.stop();
                        }

                    });
        } else {

            int historyDays = 14;

            service.getHistoricalData(mCryptos.get(i).getRaw().getFromSymbol(), "USD", historyDays, "CryptoAnalysis")
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new Observer<HistoData>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                        }

                        //in histodata, the last element is the newest, and is yesterday. it will be at position [days]
                        @Override
                        public void onNext(HistoData histoData) {

                            TimeSeries series = new BaseTimeSeries("Strategy");

                            //RUN ANALYSIS
                            Signal signal = TechnicalAnalysis.getSignal(series);

                            //INFLATE LAYOUT STUFF
                            cryptoViewHolder.mSignal.setText(signal.getSignalResult());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {

                            if (e.getMessage() != null)
                                Log.e("Histo API Error", e.getMessage());

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete() {

                            fiftyShades.stop();
                        }

                    });

        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mCryptos.size();
    }

    static class CryptoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CardView mCardView;
        TextView mCryptoDetailsOpen;
        TextView mCryptoDetailsHigh;
        TextView mCryptoDetailsLow;
        TextView mCryptoDetailsVolume;
        TextView mCryptoDetailsPercentChange;
        TextView mCryptoName;
        TextView mCryptoValue;
        TextView mCryptoSymbol;
        ConstraintLayout mCardViewDetails;
        TextView mSignal;
        TextView mRsiValueLabel;
        TextView mRsiValue;
        TextView mEmaValueLabel;
        TextView mEmaValue;
        TextView mMomentumValueLabel;
        TextView mMomentumValue;
        TextView mSignalStrength;
        TextView mLowerApi;



        CryptoViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mCryptoDetailsHigh = itemView.findViewById(R.id.crypto_details_high);
            mCryptoDetailsOpen = itemView.findViewById(R.id.crypto_details_open);
            mCryptoDetailsLow = itemView.findViewById(R.id.crypto_details_low);
            mCryptoDetailsVolume = itemView.findViewById(R.id.crypto_details_volume);
            mCryptoDetailsPercentChange = itemView.findViewById(R.id.crypto_details_percent_change);
            mCardViewDetails = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_details);
            mCardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
            mCryptoName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.crypto_name);
            mCryptoValue = itemView.findViewById(R.id.crypto_value);
            mCryptoSymbol = itemView.findViewById(R.id.crypto_symbol);
            mSignal = itemView.findViewById(R.id.signal);

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {

                mRsiValue = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rsi_indicator_value);
                mRsiValue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mEmaValue = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ema_indicator_value);
                mEmaValue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mMomentumValue = itemView.findViewById(R.id.momentum_indicator_value);
                mMomentumValue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mRsiValueLabel = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rsi_value_label);
                mRsiValueLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mEmaValueLabel = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ema_value_label);
                mEmaValueLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mMomentumValueLabel = itemView.findViewById(R.id.momentum_value_label);
                mMomentumValueLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                mLowerApi = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lowApi);
                mLowerApi.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            //mSignalStrength = itemView.findViewById(R.id.signal_strength);
        }
    }
}
```

The lines where the error is shown:

```
       for (int i = 0; i < histoData.getData().size(); i++) {

                                //create a new base bar
                                Bar bar = new BaseBar(
                                        endTime.plusDays(i),
                                        histoData.getData().get(i).getOpen(),
                                        histoData.getData().get(i).getHigh(),
                                        histoData.getData().get(i).getLow(),
                                        histoData.getData().get(i).getClose(),
                                        histoData.getData().get(i).getVolumeTo()
                                );

                                series.addBar(bar);

                            }
```

Class 2:

```
public class TechnicalAnalysis {

    //variables and their values, these dictate how likely the signal is to move one way or another.
    //Eventually, these will be tweaked and changed to be more accurate.

    private static double rsiOversold = 25;
    private static double rsiOverbought = 75;
    private static double rsiWeight = 0.35;
    private static double momentumWeight = 0.3;
    private static double emaWeight = 0.35;


    public static Signal getSignal(TimeSeries series) {

        int numBars = series.getBarCount();                 //this is the number of days in the series

        //create indicators from series
        //in all of these, the LAST member is the latest
        ClosePriceIndicator closePrices = new ClosePriceIndicator(series);
        RSIIndicator rsi = new RSIIndicator(closePrices, numBars);
        EMAIndicator shortEma = new EMAIndicator(closePrices, numBars / 4);
        EMAIndicator longEma = new EMAIndicator(closePrices, numBars);

        //init strength vars
        int rsiStrength = 0;
        int momentumStrength = 0;
        int emaStrength = 0;

        //RSI 35%

        for (int i = 0; i < numBars; i++) {
            if (rsi.getValue(i).isGreaterThanOrEqual(rsiOverbought)) {
                rsiStrength += i;
            } else if (rsi.getValue(i).isLessThanOrEqual(rsiOversold)) {
                rsiStrength -= i;
            }
        }


        //EMA 45%
        for (int i = 0; i < numBars; i++) {
            if (shortEma.getValue(i).isGreaterThan(longEma.getValue(i).multipliedBy(1.04))) {
                emaStrength += i;
            } else {
                emaStrength -= i;
            }
        }


        //MOMENTUM 20%
        for (int i = 0; i < numBars; i++) {
            if (series.getBar(i).getClosePrice().isGreaterThan(series.getBar(i).getOpenPrice())) {
                momentumStrength += i;
            } else {
                momentumStrength -= i;
            }
        }


        //finally, return the completed
        double rsiValue = rsiStrength * rsiWeight;
        double emaValue = emaStrength * emaWeight;
        double momentumValue = momentumStrength * momentumWeight;

        return new Signal(rsiValue, emaValue, momentumValue);
    }


}
```

Class 2 error:

```
isGreaterThanOrEqual
(org.ta4j.core.num.Num)
in Num cannot be applied to (double)
```

Class 2 error line:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < numBars; i++) {
            if (rsi.getValue(i).isGreaterThanOrEqual(rsiOverbought)) {
                rsiStrength += i;
            } else if (rsi.getValue(i).isLessThanOrEqual(rsiOversold)) {
                rsiStrength -= i;
            }
        }
```

Can someone help, please?

Comment: You seem to be using the library wrong: BaseBar seems to require Num objects instead of doubles, or alternatively a double to Num mapper. In your second problem it looks like Num#isGreaterThanOrEqual only accepts Num objects, whereas you're providing doubles. So you need to figure out how to convert doubles to a num object

Comment: @RoiEX  Thank you for the answer but as I mentioned already, I'm still a learner and this code was actually written by another dev from my company who no longer works. This is the reason why I came here, in hopes of saving my job as a junior dev.

Comment: Let me give you some fundamental advice:As a dev this won't be the last time you'll encounter code written by someone else and there's no way you can expect StackOverflow to do your job.So I'll tell you how to approach such a Problem.You found the GitHub repository, great.If you read the CHANGELOG.md file,you'll notice that in the most recent version a Num interface was introduced replacing a Decimal interface.If you lookup the source of this interface the Javadoc will mention DoubleNum, BigDecimalNum and PrecisionNum.Without looking I'm sure you need to use DoubleNum to convert your Doubles.

Comment: @RoiEX thank you so much for your time, help and for the advice, appreciated it! :)